# Ruby Until Conditional (Until Sorted, Sorted = True??)

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

Can someone explain this code? I got it from the solutions part of an exercise so it does run. Why isn't `sorted` compared using `==`, and why does `sorted = false` need to add `sorted` after `until`?

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted
    sorted = true
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

I would have expected the code to be like this:

```
sorted = false
until sorted == true do
```

However, when I tried to replace it with this, I get the following error:

```
eval):12: (eval):12: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):3: syntax error, unexpected kDO_COND, expecting kEND
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
                        ^
(eval):12: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
```

This is the full code that's getting the error:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted == true
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

Comment: `until sorted sorted == true`? This doesn't make any sense. Also, your implementation is now invalid. Please, get a good book on ruby.

Comment: sorry I made a typo which has now been edited, its just that this bubble sort problem has been making me confused for a while and this book is indeed confusing. Code still doesn't work with the code edited

Comment: You left out the line which sets `sorted = true` this time. Now `sorted` will never be true.

Comment: I need a sorted = true line under the "until sorted == true" line? Doesn't that sort of end the loop right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mostly confusing the algorithm with Ruby syntax.

As for as the algorithm, you are not allowed to remove `sorted = true`, the line after `until`, because your loop would never end because `sorted` never becomes true.

About Ruby syntax, what you wrote is correct, you can write the longer form of `until sorted`, which is `until sorted == true`. Your problem is removing `sorted = true` which assigns true to sorted, unless it gets false again in the `if` condition.

Comment: Yea that is the problem. I am new to programming. Thanks to you and everyone else who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse `=` and `==`. One is assignment operator and the other is comparison operator.

```
sorted = false # sets initial value for a flag
until sorted # check if the flag is true at beginning of iteration
  # code that can change `sorted`
end
```

### Update

These two forms are equivalent in this case. There's no difference. Both work.

```
until sorted
until sorted == true
```

Comment: Hey Sergio, the code above is the solution from the exercise? I agree with what you are saying and I see it the same way? Any idea why the solution would use that coding? Plus I ran the coding changing it to sorted = false and until sorted but it wouldnt run.

Comment: @JamieS: I'm not sure what you mean. The code in your question is a valid implementation of bubble sort. It works.

Comment: I dont understand why there is that extra "sorted" right after "until"

Comment: @JamieS: it's the syntax. It means, "until this expression (`sorted`) holds a truthy value"

Comment: I have looked at ruby documentation, it doesn't really explain this. i thought it was just Until x>y do .....       why do we have to mention "sorted" again in this case? Why can't just do until sorted == false ?

Comment: when i replace it with sorted == false, i am getting the following error:     eval):12: (eval):12: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):3: syntax error, unexpected kDO_COND, expecting kEND
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
                            ^
(eval):12: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end

Comment: I don't know. Works for me. Post full code that gives you error